# building from source on OSX - c++

Tags: c++, macos, vtk, itk

I almost know nothing from `c++` and I am trying to build `ITK` tool from source on `10.10 OSX`. So I followed strictly the doc, when I try to `make` I get, bunch of duplicate errors

```
duplicate symbol ___sputc in:
    CMakeFiles/itktiff.dir/tif_aux.o
    CMakeFiles/itktiff.dir/tif_unix.o
ld: 69 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/libitktiff.3.16.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Utilities/itktiff/CMakeFiles/itktiff.dir/all] Error 2
```

I get messages colored in red such as `Linking CXX shared library ../../../bin/libitkgdcm.dylib` (red means error ?)

then I get at the end

```
[ 44%] Built target itkgdcm
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I read that building `ITK` in newest `OSX` version is not simple due to `clang`'s new paths, and that one should have to set a flag like that : `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++11` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++03` but none worked.

Could someone help ?

Comment: Hm...never had the money to afford a MAC...but... MAC is kinda BSD-based. And under BSD, usually the standard libs are not libstdc++ but libc++, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @BitTickler ok let's give it a try

Comment: @BitTickler now I get error "sooner" `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream<char>') and 'long')
   if (*fp == NULL)
`

Comment: What version of `ITK` are you compiling - I think you need at least version 4.4 to work on Mavericks/Yosemite?

Comment: @Petesh yes I trying to compile 3.16 - and that's the version I need

Comment: It's not supported to compile. I expect you're using `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true CMakeLists.txt`, which is where the issue is arising. Try with the static libraries, rather than the shared ones i.e. remove that option from `cmake`. Otherwise you may have to bite the bullet on an upgrade.

Comment: @Petesh I am using shared libraries and I ll try static ones !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting spurious symbols in the library that should not be there.

The official workaround is to use a newer version of the ITK tools, but if you have to use the older version, then you need to configure with the C option `-std=gnu89` to make the inlining behave in the way that should make this work.

OSX ships with two c++ libraries - the one that clang defaults to `libc++` and the one that official gcc defaults to `libstdc++`, if you're compiling multiple C++ projects to build to the ultimate target, then you have to ensure that they all compile with the same C++ standard library.

On the presumption that you're planning on linking with `libstdc++`, as that's what you've indicated, I've updated the compilation instructions as so:

This means that you should run clang with the options:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-std=gnu89 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++03" CMakeLists.txt
```

The file `Code/Common/itkKLMSegmentationBorder.h` has a couple of references to `rhs.m_Pointer` which should be `rhs->m_Pointer` - the compiler makes this an obvious error.

There are a lot of template method instantion confusion issues, I've added a few references here:

line 657 in `Utilities/vxl/core/vnl/vnl_matrix_fixed_ref.h` add a `this->` prefix to the invocation of `equal`

The file `Code/Common/itkParametricPath.txx` at lines 46, 137 needs an added this-> before all the invocations of `Evaluate`

Same issue with `Code/Numerics/Statistics/itkWeightedCentroidKdTreeGenerator.txx`, at lines 120, 126 with the invocations of `GenerateTreeLoop`

Same issue with `Code/BasicFilters/itkTernaryFunctorImageFilter.txx`, at lines 49, 62 & 75 with the invocation of `SetNthInput`

Same issue with `Testing/Code/Common/itkMeshSourceGraftOutputTest.cxx`, at line 153 in the invocation of `GraftOutput`

`SetNthInvocation` issues with `Code/BasicFilters/itkBloxBoundaryPointImageToBloxBoundaryProfileImageFilter.txx`

> There are more, but they're a relatively tedious fix to get it to compile. I've put a [pastebin of the diff up](http://pastebin.com/sLmC67m9), which should be OK, although it was from a slightly unclean version so there may be some changes missing.

I gave up trying to fix getting it to compile with `libc++` - ambiguity issues with `abs` was the start and there are probably more, so I don't feel it's worth pursuing.